# How do I force the creation of tables using SQLPackage after renaming the table in the pre-deploy script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

According to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49280/224211) to another question, I should be able to rename an existing table in a pre-deployment script and that the dacpac should recreate the original table during the deployment process. However, the problem that I encountered is that the table doesn't get recreated and instead I get errors when a view or stored procedure uses that table. Is there a way to force the creation of a renamed table with the original name during the deployment process?

I did used the /Properties:CreateNewDatabase=True but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Can you post the sqlpackage command and switches you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CreateNewDatabase option is defined as "Specifies whether the target database should be updated or whether it should be dropped and re-created when you publish to a database."

Therefore to keep the renamed table you need to perform an update and therefore `/Properties:CreateNewDatabase=False`

I think you need the following switche included:

`DropObjectsNotInSource=FALSE`     Specifies whether objects that do not exist in the database snapshot (.dacpac) file will be dropped from the target database when you publish to a database. This value takes precedence over DropExtendedProperties.

`/Properties:BlockWhenDriftDetected=False`  Specifies whether to block updating a database whose schema no longer matches its registration or is unregistered.

Comment: Setting those flags didn't work. The renamed table didn't get recreated during the deployment step.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I cleaned up other parameters and it seems to work. I'd list them but there's a lot of them.

Comment: :-)   yes - there are a lot and some of them can be contradictory. Glad you worked it out.